# Value not bind to the view from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two select tags as follow

```
 <%= f.select(:floor_id, ProjectFloor.find(:all,:order => "name ASC",:conditions => ["project_id = ?", @project.id]).collect{|b|[b.name, b.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select'}) %>

 <%= f.select(:unit_id, @floor.collect{|b|[b.name, b.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select'}) %>
```

When the user select the value on the first select tag called `:floor_id` then the value of the select tag data should be load to `:unit_id` select tag

I have try the following to read and fetch the data but. the floor_id always receiving **null**

My controller method is as follow :

```
@floor_id = params[:floor_id]
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@proposed_customer = ProposedCustomer.new
@floor = ProjectFloorUnit.select_units(@project.id, @floor_id)
```

The select unit method is work fine for static values so it must work if we pass the proper param.

Comment: what is `f` there? If you don't use `floor_id` from model object, then you better use `select_tag` instead of `f.select`

Comment: When you select an option in the first select tag, it doesn't automatically send the request to the server, not until you explicitly specify this.

Comment: It means do we need to push any API call to to the server ?

Answer (score 2):

When a page is completely loaded, it disconnects from the server. So, you need to initiate a separate request, and the response of the request will change the values or whatever you want in the second dropdown.

You can use jQuery to send a new request:

```
$("#floorIDSelectTag").change(function() {
  var floorID = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    type: '',
    url: '',
    // other things
    success: function(data) {
      // Here, you need to use the data from the request's response,
      // and update the things in 2nd dropdown
    }
  });
});
```

What will be the URL that you will use in AJAX call? For it, you need to build a new route in `config/routes.rb` file, a new action in your controller, and send back the data in JSON format. Something like following:

```
def get_data_for_floor_id
  @floor_id = params[:floor_id]
  # Do the other stuff, and prepare the response you need to send.
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {  }
  end
end
```